# Как передать данные программе через скрипт bash?

Tags: linux, bash, скрипт

Не совсем понимаю как можно пережать данные в программу через скрипт bash? У меня есть программа на С++, которая принимает на вход две строки разделанные  '\n'.

```
#!/bin/bash
./a.out & echo "abcd" & echo "abcd"

echo "end prog"
```

Comment: А это оринально использовать выполнение в фоне. Красиво разложенные грабли.

Comment: Я думаю - это опечатка. На самом деле, TS имел в виду: ./a.out && echo "abcd" && echo "abcd" Это даёт логическое выражение. По правилам оптимизации, сначала вычислится самый левый опреанд и только если он даст "Истина" будет вычисляться второй, ну и так далее... Это известный трюк на shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

отправить данные процессу на его *stdin* можно например, так:

```
$ echo -e "первая строка\nвторая строка" | ./a.out
```

или, если данные записаны в файле, например, так:

```
$ cat файл | ./a.out
```